# Pass row templates to vue boostrap table from parent component using slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a component called "List" which contains a vue boostrap table:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table :items="items">
      <!--<template slot="createdAt" slot-scope="row"> usually vue boostrap table row templates live here-->
        <!--{{row.item.createdAt|dateFormatter}}-->
      <!--</template>-->
      <slot name="tableTemplates"></slot> <!-- but i want to pass the templates from my parent template -->
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm passing the table items from my parent Component "Orders". I also want to pass row templates to the vue boostrap b-table component.

Unfortunately i can't get it to work using slots (That would be a template inside a template)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <list :items="items">
      <template slot="tableTemplates">
        <!--templates inside templates do not work-->
        <template slot="id" slot-scope="row">
          <span v-b-tooltip.hover :title="row.item.id">{{row.item.id|uuidFormatter}}</span>
        </template>
        <template slot="createdAt" slot-scope="row">
          {{row.item.createdAt|dateFormatter}}
        </template>
        <template slot="customer" slot-scope="row">
          {{row.item.customer}}
        </template>
      </template>
    </list>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you considered creating actual components instead of using just `template`s?

Comment: You may also be able to use [inline templates](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Inline-Templates).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just change IVO's answer and make your List component generic.
Here is one possible way to do that:

List component template:

```
<template>
  <b-table striped hover :items="items">
    <template :slot="slot.field" slot-scope="row" v-for="slot in slots">
      <slot :name="slot.name" :tbl="row"></slot>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</template>
```

List component props:

```
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array
    },
    slots: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
```

Then, in any parent components (using List), you can define a `templates` data property, with an array of template instructions to be passed to the List component. In the example, I used an array of objects to pass the dynamic slot name and table data field.

Parent component `templates` data property:

```
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      templates: [
        {
          name: "templateName",
          field: "dataFieldName"
        },
        ...
      ]
    };
  },
```

Parent component template, List usage:

```
  <list :items="items" :slots="templates">
    <template slot="customSlotName" slot-scope="data">
        // Custom template here...
    </template>
  </list>
```

This will keep all your custom template logic living in the parent component, ex. Order.vue, and not in List.vue.

Here is the updated codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/244p9rx10n

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried like that ? You get the scope from the table's slot and then provide this scope inside your nested slot:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table :items="items">
      <template slot-scope="row">
        <slot name="tableTemplates" :tbl-props="row"></slot>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working for me. Here is a codesandbox with your suggestion: https://codesandbox.io/s/z2mw6j7l4x

Comment: Updated the code https://codesandbox.io/s/m41zoz0q5p as you were not using my suggestion properly.

Comment: I don't want to define a slot like "last_name" in my "abstract"-kind of List.vue component. I want my model and my model specific templates (like "last_name") to live in Orders.vue

Comment: If you do not define it you can not access the scope of the slot - which means you can not access a grand-child from a grand-father.